# Routing in MVC doesn't always work correct

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing

My problem is as simple as the title.

I want to link to an action from a controller, but doesn't always work. I know what the problem is, but don't know how to solve it.

Imagine you're at the home page, the URL is then something like this:  `localhost:1234/`. When I use the following URL in a link (`<a>`-tag) to go to the action `configure`, the `href` in that link-tag will then look like this: `configure`. But this doesn't work because it will send the user to `localhost:1234/configure`. Instead of this it should be `localhost:1234/device/configure` where `device` is the controller.

I could change the `href` in the link-tag to `device/configure`, but then it wouldn't work anymore when the user is redirected to the homepage. Because the url of the homepage is then `localhost:1234/device/view` (the default route, configured in RouteConfig.cs) and the link will send the user to `localhost:1234/device/device/configure`

I've already tried to use `@Url.Action` and `@Html.ActionLink`, but that doesn't work either.

Does anyone know how to make sure it will always send the user to the right URL?

[Here](https://gyazo.com/feff9e769ea5ea35c292db104ebe25c3.png) is my RouteConfig if you need it.

Comment: Maybe you could show us your RouteConfig?

Comment: @BonMacalindong Done

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
@Html.ActionLink("link text", "configure", "device")
```

Comment: As I've said in my post: "I've already tried to use `@Url.Action` and `@Html.ActionLink`, but that doesn't work either." - M Zeinstra, 2016

Comment: Could you try it and inspect the anchor to know what is the genereted href. I have just test it and it seems to work for me

Comment: Oh sorry, it suddenly it works :D Thanks :) Could you edit your answer so I can upvote it, because I can't upvote anymore, unless you edit your answer.